# Update the value at a certain position for every two rows an array

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a *n-by-m* matrix with zeros and my row number is always even. For the first and second row, I want to update the first element to be `1`, 3rd and 4th the second element to be `1` etc.

So if my original matrix is

```
 [0,0,0
  0,0,0
  0,0,0
  0,0,0
  0,0,0
  0,0,0]
```

I would like my resulting matrix to be:

```
 [1,0,0
  1,0,0
  0,1,0
  0,1,0
  0,0,1
  0,0,1]
```

Comment: Do you want to generate the second matrix, or to specifically assign that specific pattern to a matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution using indexing:

```
m=6;
n=3;
A = zeros(m,n);
A(1:m+2:end)=1;
A(2:m+2:end)=1;
```

Result:

```
A =

   1   0   0
   1   0   0
   0   1   0
   0   1   0
   0   0   1
   0   0   1
```

Comment: @Tony It does. Good job, rahnema1! Simpler than mine

Comment: @Luis Mendo I tried with octava online and it didn't this is why I asked him :).

Comment: @Tony It seems to [work](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@59ra2HNlWdrbM3lqGCrUJValF@skauTpwnkaxha5WobWaXmpWjaGoL4Rij8lMziAg1Hzf//AQ) for me on Octave 4.0.3

Comment: @Luis Mendo I checked the version I am running at using `version` and it says `4.0.1-rcl`.

Comment: @TonyTannous sorry for late reply I wasn't online. It works on `Octave Online`

Answer (score 2):

Your question can have two possible interpretations. The simpler one is just to get the second matrix. It is a diagonal matrix with each row repeated twice. This can be done easily with [`kron`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html):

```
x = kron(eye(3), [2, 1])
```

If you want to find the pattern of indices that results in the correct assignment of ones, you can just use the above expression to generate a boolean mask, then apply it to an arbitrary input (in your case `zeros(6, 3)`):

```
x = zeros(6, 3);
mask = kron(eye(3, 'logical'), [2, 1]);
x(mask) = 1
```

Comment: @Adriaan. Thanks. Spotted the numpy user :)

Answer (score 1):

This works even if `n` does not equal `2*m`

```
x = zeros(6,4); % example with n=6, m = 4
[n, m] = size(x);
m = min(m,n/2);
x(bsxfun(@plus, 1:n, n*floor(0:.5:m-.5))) = 1;
```

gives

```
x =
     1     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0
     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sortrows([eye(3);eye(3)],'descend')

ans =

     1     0     0
     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
     0     0     1
```

Or, if you already have your matrix:

```
A = zeros(6,3);
a = 1; % Or whatever arbitrary number.
jj=1;
for ii = 1:2:size(A,1)
    A(ii:ii+1,jj)=[a;a];
    jj=jj+1;
end
```

Comment: what if I want -1 instead of 1?

Comment: Then you fill in `-1` instead of `1`, obviously?

Comment: @user3669481. I think I answered that for you.

Comment: @Adriaan I meant if I use the eye() function that you provided in the first solution

Comment: Multiply with `-1` @user3669481

Comment: Alternatively, premultiply the `eye`s by -1 and remove the `'descend'` argument from `sortrows`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yea, but that'd only work for negative numbers though. Multiplying afterwards with a fixed constant it more general I'd say (though your solution obviously is way better and far more general)

Comment: @Adriaan That's true.